# How can I save a file name in a matrix and the result on each iteration (for-loop) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, save, filenames

I have a folder with 140 (*. txt) files and I need save in a matrix these files names and the result of the process in a for-loop. I have tried this:

```
class= fullfile('*.txt'); 
D = dir(class);

%% for-loop

data=zeros(length(D),2);

for kk=1:length(D);

   blockname = D(kk).name;

    %process > result(kk);

 data(kk,1)=result(kk); 
 data(kk,2)= blockname;

 end
```

but this error message is displayed

data(kk,2)= blockname;
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Because

blockname =

block_100.txt

I don't have any idea how solve it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by "the result of the process", however, one of the solutions to your question is

```
clear all
clc

D = dir('*.txt');
data = cell(length(D), 2);

for kk=1:length(D);

 blockname = D(kk).name;

 %process > result(kk);

 data{kk,1}= kk; %<-- replace kk with whatever you mean by the result of the process
 data{kk,2}= blockname;

end

data
```

The result is

data =

```
[1]    'AA.txt'
[2]    'BB.txt'
[3]    'CC.txt'
```

To access elements of data, you do `data(1,1)` for the first element and so on.

You can carry out the solution without utilizing the loop, therefore, an alternative solution is

```
clear all
clc

D = dir('*.txt');
data = cell(length(D), 2);

data(:,1) = {1}; %<-- replace 1 with whatever the result of the process is
data(:,2) = {D(:).name};
data
```

The result is

data =

```
[1]    'AA.txt'
[1]    'BB.txt'
[1]    'CC.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, you cannot mix numbers and string in a matrix. You have to use cell to do so. Try writing the same code using {} instead of ().

```
data{kk,1} = result(kk);
data{kk,2} = blockname;
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you had taken to answer. It works perfectly! Thanks again